# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' Web Scraping Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on an office project to get data to check active status on different websites but whenever I want to get data sometimes it shows none and sometimes it shows this Attribute error, I follow youtube videos steps but still get this error. help, please.

//Python Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get(
    "https://www.mintscan.io/cosmos/validators/cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
status = soup.find('div', {'class': "ValidatorInfo_statusBadge__PBIGr"})
para = status.find('p').text
print(para)
```

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`'lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR try to use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And you can try this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually get `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: in question you could add link to video which you watched. And you could check how old is this video - maybe page changed content and now old video is useless.

Answer (score 1):

The url is dynamic meaning data is populated by javascript. So you need automation tool something like selenium.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


url = 'https://www.mintscan.io/cosmos/validators/cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
#driver.close()

status = soup.find('div', {'class': "ValidatorInfo_statusBadge__PBIGr"})
para = status.find('p').text
print(para)
```

Output:

```
Active
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the most common problem - modern pages use `JavaScript` to add elements but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript.

So `soup.find('div',...)` gives `None` instead expected element and later it makes problem with `None.find('p')`

You may use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

url = "https://www.mintscan.io/cosmos/validators/cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw"

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)

#status = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ValidatorInfo_statusBadge__PBIGr"]')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
status = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ValidatorInfo_statusBadge__PBIGr"]')))
print(status.text)
```

---

Eventually you should check if page gives some API to get data.

You may also use `DevTools` (tab: `Network`) to check if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL and you may try to use this URL with `requests`. It could work faster than with Selenium but server may detect script/bot and block it.

JavaScript usually get data as JSON so it may not need to scrape HTML with `BeautifulSoup`